# PHP foreach different arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to see all addresses, amounts, and confirmations foreach transaction - except each array is different.  How can I get all this information from the litecoind's response?

```
                foreach($transactions as $transaction) {

                    echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['address'];
                    echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['amount'];
                    echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['confirmations'];

                }
```

Above is the PHP Code, the response comes from these lines:

```
$transactions = $litecoin->listreceivedbyaddress();


var_dump($transactions);


array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["address"]=> string(34) "LPwNe6JtUgXxWrdK26UMKJJrDwYzEzkUZY" ["account"]=> string(0) "" ["amount"]=> float(1) ["confirmations"]=> int(4) ["txids"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(64) "9da67825c00cf01c991e2fa913cc82c59d558b4c41d8f4e3dcb8f862b81affec" } } [1]=> array(5) { ["address"]=> string(34) "LTfP4riFBn6ctQ9jbGyWZ2HswmUZKgrJbX" ["account"]=> string(0) "" ["amount"]=> float(1) ["confirmations"]=> int(537) ["txids"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(64) "b9806a0adc91ef70e67341f7d0cf6f2c7422fac35e54062153318d4416f44eaf" } } }
```

This is what it returns:

```
LPwNe6JtUgXxWrdK26UMKJJrDwYzEzkUZY
1
4
LPwNe6JtUgXxWrdK26UMKJJrDwYzEzkUZY
1
4
```

As you can see it returns the same thing, how can I have it return the two different transactions?  Thanks.

Comment: Can't you at least read a single tutorial on php before asking ? You are looping on the array but always accessing the first entry ...

Comment: Not even close..?  Completely different...

Comment: http://php.net/manual <- good stuff in there, for example http://php.net/array  http://php.net/arrays http://php.net/foreach

Comment: OP did good trial, we all did similar mistake, asking for help is not bad if there is also a trial and effort.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the array's first element every time. Use the variable `$transaction` which will take on each value of the array in turn.

change:

```
echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['address'];
```

to

```
echo '<br />' . $transaction['address'];
```

and similarly for the other lines.

Comment: Sounds like you wanted to comment about a typo somebody made... .

Comment: huh? I stand by this code.

Comment: @LynHeadley: It'd probably be more answerworthy if you explained why those lines should change.  Just saying "type this" doesn't teach anything, and basically ensures that we have another generation of programmers that don't know how to work with arrays. :P

Comment: cHao ok I have explained.

Comment: @LynHeadley: Much better, IMO.  +1

Answer (score -1):

> how can I have it return the two different transactions?

By iterating over both transactions, let's say you have them in an array called `$array`, then it works like:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

That simple it is, really. Compare http://php.net/foreach.

Now compare with your code, you're not that far away:

On the one hand you obviously foreach that `$transactions` array:

```
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) 
{
    ...
}
```

Because you get two-times some output.

But on the other hand you doesn't foreach that `$transactions` array:

```
    echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['address'];    
    echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['amount'];
    echo '<br />' . $transactions[0]['confirmations'];
```

So you probably should decide what you want. Foreaching the array or just accessing it by it's numeric indecies. PHP will do as you write the code for it.

As you've got experienced both works. To see your code in foreach action:

```
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    var_dump($transaction);
}
```

And to see it in non-foreach action:

```
var_dump($transactions[0]);
var_dump($transactions[1]);
```

which is just accessing the array, compare http://php.net/arrays